# Is this a solution to one of Zeno's paradoxes?

Tags: paradox, zeno-of-elea

I was inspired by [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask) invoking a notion of a "Supertask" (informally, an infinite sequence of operations performed in a finite amount of time) to pose Zeno's paradox.

To my understanding, the paradox is posed as this: since motion must cross half of the path between A and B, then half the path therein, and so on, motion is a Supertask.

My question is this: can't we apply the same halving argument to time, so that an infinite number of time-segments is used in the process of motion? Therefore, motion wouldn't be a Supertask. (A little more formally: if both time and 1-dimensional space are assumed to be segments of the reals, then any halving argument constructing infinite cells out of these segments can be applied to both time and space. Then we're only traversing an infinite sequence of cells of space in infinite cells of time, which is not a supertask.)

What's wrong with this argument? (Or, does it work?)

Comment: No. Since supertask is a countable sequence of actions performed in a finite interval of time, and the interval remains finite no matter how it is chopped up, it would still be a supertask. And even if we agreed not to call it that verbal relabeling does not solve anything. The solution is that imaginary chopping up of space does not create real actions in the first place, so motion isn't a supertask anyway. If Achilles had to actually wave his hand at each half marker that would be a different matter.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it except that it contradicts known physics. You can speculate on future unknown physics though. That makes it science fiction.

Comment: Since Zeno's paradox is known to be wrong, it shouldn't be applied to time, or anything else.

Comment: @Conifold but if we consider t_1 - t_0 a finite interval of time, can't we consider x_1 - x_0 a finite interval of space, which remains finite no matter how it is chopped up?

Comment: Agreed re: zeno not reflecting known physics here. Just interested in testing the (abstract?) soundness of the original posed problem.

Comment: It is finite, but a countable sequence of subintervals still fits into it. There is no symmetry between countable and finite in the definition of supertask, they refer to different things, cardinality vs measure.

Comment: @user4894 Zeno's paradox neither reflects nor does not reflect physics, known or future, it has nothing to do with it. The paradox is in apparent contradiction between two claims both of which we find initially plausible: supertasks can not be performed, motion is a supertask when looked at in a certain way. It is paradoxical with whatever physics or mathematics, the issue is philosophical.

Comment: I see. Then I guess I would take issue with the second claim (of zeno's paradox), that supertasks are impossible, since if the supertask involves a converging amount of "work", then it would not be impossible.

Comment: Indeed, that is the issue. It is too loose an idea of what amounts to "supertask" that is responsible for the intuitive plausibility of both claims. Upon analysis, it has to be taken to mean two different things (real actions vs thought up abstractions) for both to come out as true. But intuition conflates the two into one, and this equivocation creates the appearance of a contradiction. However, there is a deeper meaning to the paradox not captured by light supertask interpretations, see [Why Mathematical Solutions of Zeno’s Paradoxes Miss The Point](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2304/).

Comment: So what's interesting, is that in computing, an infinitely recursive task which yet involves a decreasing amount of "work" on each call such that "work" converges, would still involve a diverging amount of time, because there is fixed cost associated with each function call added to the stack. (Depending on your computing model.) This consumes space and/or time unboundedly... perhaps this is the sort of thing Zeno was talking about. If you cut up the task differently, e.g. doing all the work in one call, you get a different result. (Nice paper linked, btw.)

Comment: I do not think that motion is properly conceptualized as a supertask even with converging amount of work (without fixed cost of steps). Representation of time/work by real numbers is a mathematical abstraction, and while we are are free to divide real number intervals as we wish in abstraction nothing real corresponds to it. Beyond some small scale such divisions can not even be done in principle. Not everything that can be done in mathematical models has physical meaning, it is equally pointless to ask whether the length of some real object is rational or irrational, for example.